# Can't get the right AST selector for history.push()

Tags: eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm migrating a codebase from `react-router` v5 to v6, and I'd like to add an `eslint` rule forbidding `history.push` calls with a [`no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax).

Using the [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) with `history.push();` as the input, it seems to me that the `history` and `push` `Identifier` nodes are adjacent siblings, so I should be able to catch the call with `selector: 'Identifier[name="history"] + Identifier[name="push"]'`, but as you can check on [ESLint Playground](https://eslint.org/play#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) it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for `history.push()`:

```
/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: ['error', 'CallExpression[callee.object.name="history"][callee.property.name="push"]'] */
history.push();
```